# Python: Print each group of n values to a new column in CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have written a script that simulates the Gambler's Ruin problem. Currently, I'm printing the Monte Carlo point number and the outcome of the scenario to the console. I'm currently printing the output of 10,000 points to a dataframe and the results look like this in the console:

MC = 0 Outcome = 0

MC = 1 Outcome = 10

MC = 2 Outcome = 10

What I would like to do is write code so that I can export my results to CSV and have the end result look like this:

MC = 0 Outcome = 0   MC = 3  Outcome = 0 MC = 6 Outcome = 10

MC = 1 Outcome = 10 MC = 4 Outcome = 10 MC = 7 Outcome = 0

MC = 2 Outcome = 10 MC = 5 Outcome = 0 MC = 8 Outcome = 10

Basically, I'd like to have each group of n rows (in this case each group of 100 rows, starting at the 100th row) be output to a new column in the same csv.

Here's my pathetic attempt:

```py
data={'MC Point':[i],'Outcome':[money]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Even that isn't working like I thought it would as the CSV is only capturing the 10,000th outcome. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want all items `MC[i] Outcome = [money]` to go inside a new column after every 3 index? Or do you need all `MC[i] Outcome = [money]` one after other, either of them saved in CSV?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by all items. What I'm wanting is to have the first 100 rows in column A, the 2nd 100 rows in column B, the third 100 rows in column C, and so on until each group of 100 rows is in its own column. Think of MC =0 Outcome = 0 through MC = 99 Outcome = 0 as it's own column, then I want MC =100 Outcome = 0 through MC =199 Outcome = 0 in it's own column and so on.

Comment: I have suggested a method in the answer, be careful to handle last row if total number of elements are not a multiple of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataFrame

Add Values to a list for every iteration

Add Columns to DataFrame from our generated list after its length is the same as the number of rows, you can use any preferred method

Write the DataFrame to csv

Also, you can generalize this code for any rows, by changing `100` from the code

Note your rows have to be of the same length, so you need to handle the case for the last row if the number of elements is not equal to 100, by filling some dummy values (work with a numpy array and assign on index), or some other preferred method.

```py
i = 0
elements = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    if i % 100 == 0:
        df['Column' + str(i/100)] = elements
        elements = []
    else:
        elements.append("MC Point : [{}] Outcome : [{}]".format(i, money)) # data for corresponding `i` here,
# you can choose your own way to create your string here, or your own type
    
    i += 1

    # Add a break statement here for the end of elements, for ex:
    # if i >= total number of elements:
    # break

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```